# Disable wordpress autoformatting

Tags: wordpress, autoformatting

everyone!

A little headsup:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');  
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
```

These do not work. Please, don't suggest any plugins and functions related to those.

Problem: I have specific HTML that has to stay as it is in page content:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="button chrome-button open-lightbox" data-lightbox-id="call-request"><div class="svg-icons svg-phone-brown"></div>Заказать звонок</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="button chrome-button open-lightbox" data-lightbox-id="service-request"><div class="svg-icons svg-list-brown"></div>Заказать расчет</a>
```

But when I switch to visual editor and modify anything (even if outside of this HTML part) it turns it into

```
<a class="button chrome-button open-lightbox" data-lightbox-id="call-request">
</a>
<div class="svg-icons svg-phone-brown"></div>
Заказать звонок
<a class="button chrome-button open-lightbox" data-lightbox-id="service-request">
</a>
<div class="svg-icons svg-list-brown"></div>
Заказать расчет
```

It's just one example. The editor changes a lot of stuff, even though it's W3C valid.

Question: How do I make the visual editor not autoformat HTML at all? Is that actually possible?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Just in case, my wordpress version is 4.4.10

Comment: These filters you mentioned are for doing this stuff for display only. What you're looking for is when it's being saved into the db.

Comment: Yes, but there are a lot of people who would google it and give inappropriate answers. So I posted that in order not to receive any of those. Plus, I think it's not while saving to the db, but when it is modified by the editor